# In Rally, how to get list of fields with attribute type using web service v2.0

Tags: java, web-services, rally

[image]

For example get field Environment with Attribute Type in JSON Form using only web-service v2.0 of Rally.

Comment: Your question is tagged java- are you looking for an example of how to do this using the Rally Rest Toolkit for Java?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java code that prints Severity values of Defect:

```
public class GetSeverityValues {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String projectRef = "/project/12352608219";
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/12352608129"; 
            String applicationName = "RESTExampleFindSeverityValues";

            RallyRestApi restApi = null;

        try {
                restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                        new URI(host),
                        username,
                        password);
                restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 

                QueryRequest  typeDefRequest = new QueryRequest("TypeDefinition");
                typeDefRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("ObjectID","Attributes"));
                typeDefRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
                typeDefRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Name", "=", "Defect"));

                QueryResponse typeDefQueryResponse = restApi.query(typeDefRequest);
                JsonObject typeDefJsonObject = typeDefQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
                System.out.println(typeDefJsonObject.get("_ref"));
                System.out.println(typeDefJsonObject.get("Attributes"));

                int numberOfAttributes = typeDefJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Attributes").get("Count").getAsInt();

                    QueryRequest attributeRequest = new QueryRequest(typeDefJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("Attributes"));
                    attributeRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("AllowedValues","ElementName", "Name"));
                    QueryResponse attributesQueryResponse = restApi.query(attributeRequest);
                    for (int i=0; i<attributesQueryResponse.getResults().size();i++){
                        String fieldName = attributesQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Name").getAsString();
                        if (fieldName.equals("Severity")){
                            JsonObject allowedValuesJsonObject = attributesQueryResponse.getResults().get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                            int numberOfSeverityValues = allowedValuesJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("AllowedValues").get("Count").getAsInt();
                            //System.out.println(numberOfSeverityValues);
                            QueryRequest allowedValuesRequest = new QueryRequest(allowedValuesJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("AllowedValues"));
                            allowedValuesRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("StringValue"));
                            QueryResponse allowedValuesResponse = restApi.query(allowedValuesRequest);
                            for (int j = 0; j < numberOfSeverityValues; j++){   
                                JsonObject allowedAttributeValuesJsonObject = allowedValuesResponse.getResults().get(j).getAsJsonObject();
                                System.out.println(allowedAttributeValuesJsonObject.get("StringValue"));
                            }
                        }
                    }

        }
        finally{
            if (restApi != null) {
                restApi.close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```